# How to print the directory tree?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is there a way to print the directory tree with all files contained ?

Comment: Have you tried the `dir` command? That combined with `ShellExecute` may be the simplest solution.

Comment: This my help: http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/652.html

Comment: @Golez: Depends on what's meant by "print". If you want to print it to a printer, I imagine it's a lot faster to redirect the output of `dir` than to code up the recursive solution you describe. But yeah, I'll grant I didn't give that a lot of effort and it wasn't intended to be a real answer.

Comment: If this is on windows, don't forget the DOS 'tree' command.  Surprising little tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the FindFirstFile and FindNextFile api. Use these recursively (or even better, using a stack) to find the entire directory structure.
[MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How would using a stack be better? It's a lot of extra hassle and unless you can expect a depth of 1000+ levels, stack overflows shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: It shouldn't really be a problem, but it's not much extra work. But feel free to build a recursive function. It will work and is indeed a little easier.

Comment: If you do a recursive algorithm on any windows box out there (all being x86) you will be using a stack. Just not a `std::stack` =P

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable mean for directory operations in std c++. If you have boost, use boost filesystem. Otherwise you could take a look, how it is implemented in some portable libraries like Qt, wxWidgets, boost.

Comment: Considering the question is tagged "Windows", I'm not sure why a portable method is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all directories and all files (including those where you don't have access rights for) you can use Change Journals. The drawback is that it's pretty complicated.

http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/journal/journal.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1099/journal2/journal2.aspx